# What's the proper way of returning a result out of a IO coroutine job?

Tags: kotlin, file, io, kotlin-coroutines

The problem is very simple, but I can't really seem to wrap my head around it. I'm launching a non-blocking thread in the IO scope in order to read from a file. However, I can't get the result in time before I return from the method - it always returns the initial empty value "". What am I missing here?

```
private fun getFileContents(): String {
        var result = ""
        val fileName = getFilename()
        val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            kotlin.runCatching {
                val file = getFile(fileName)
                file.openFileInput().use { inputStream ->
                    result = String(inputStream.readBytes(), Charsets.UTF_8)
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coroutines are launched asynchronously. Your non-suspending function cannot wait for the result without blocking. For more information about why asynchronous code results in your function returning with the default result, [read the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o?r=Saves_AllUserSaves).

`getFileContents()` has to be a suspend function to be able to return something without blocking, in which case you don't need to launch a coroutine either. But then whatever calls this function must be in a suspend function or coroutine.

```
private suspend fun getFileContents(): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val fileName = getFilename()
    kotlin.runCatching {
        val file = getFile(fileName)
        file.openFileInput().use { inputStream ->
            result = String(inputStream.readBytes(), Charsets.UTF_8)
        }
    }.getOrDefault("")
}
```

There are two "worlds" of code: either you are in a suspending/coroutine context or you are not. When you are in a function that is not a suspend function, you can only return results that can be computed immediately, or you can block until the result is ready.

Generally, if you're using coroutines, you launch a coroutine at some high level in your code, and then you are free to use suspend functions everywhere because almost all of your code is initially triggered by a coroutine. By "high level", I mean you launch the coroutine when a UI screen appears or a UI button is pressed, for example.

Basically, your coroutine launches are usually in UI listeners and UI event functions, not in lower-level code like the function in your question. The coroutine calls a suspend function, which can call other suspend functions, so you don't need to launch more coroutines to perform your various sequential tasks.

---

The alternate solution is to return a `Deferred` with the result, like this:

```
private fun getFileContents(): Deferred<String> {
    val fileName = getFilename()
    return CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
        kotlin.runCatching {
            val file = getFile(fileName)
            file.openFileInput().use { inputStream ->
                result = String(inputStream.readBytes(), Charsets.UTF_8)
            }
        }.getOrDefault("")
    }
}
```

But to unpack the result, you will need to call `await()` on the Deferred instance inside a coroutine somewhere.

Comment: I wonder if it's worth clarifying the bit about launches usually being in UI listeners/event-functions so it applies to non-UI based apps too.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! I admit I totally forgot about the waiting part in coroutines and how it was achieved.